# Knockout - cross input binding/observable

Tags: data-binding, observable, knockout-3.0

I want to create a observable binding like a image resize calculation. After a few days of trying to accomplish it by my self I get frustrated. Perhaps someone can help me out. 
The view has two input fields with numbers. Lets say the first 800 and the second 600. When I change the number in the first input field, the second should also update but with a calculation for proportional resizing. So for this task, I need the old and new value from the first input field and make a calculation with the value from the second input field. The result should then passed to the second input field. This should work also vista verca.

EDIT: After a little bit distance I think I found a working solution. Below I post the code so when someone has a suggestion for a improvement, your welcome:

```
// View has custom binding handler 'dimensionBinding' bound to an observable. Additional it put the contrary observable to the allBindings object.
 <input data-bind="dimensionBinding: valueHeight, contrary: valueWidth" type="number" >
 <input data-bind="dimensionBinding: valueWidth, contrary: valueHeight" type="number" >

    // viewModel
        self.valueHeight = ko.observable(800);
        self.valueWidth = ko.observable(600);

    // bindingHandlers
    ko.bindingHandlers.dimensionBinding = {
        init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {

// get the initially value from the observable and put it into the view        
$(element).val( ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()) );
        $(element).on('change', function(event) {
            // get the value from the contrary input field
            const contraryValue = ko.unwrap(allBindings.get('contrary')); 
            // get the value from this input before change
            const valueBeforeChange = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()); 
            // get the new value from this input field
            const newValue = event.target.value; 
            // calc proportional and set the returning value to the contrary observable
            allBindings.get('contrary')( contraryValue / valueBeforeChange * newValue)
            valueAccessor()(newValue)    
        });
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        const value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        // update the view
        $(element).val(value);
    }
};
```